# Have I just created a security issue by using str_replace to escape apostrophes?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working with a really old "Page Builder" on a clients site. Every time I put some text with an `'` in it the text is output on the page as `\'`.

I have tried some different functions but couldn't find a solution except for using the `str_replace` version below:

```
$output .= wpautop(do_shortcode(htmlspecialchars_decode(str_replace("\'","'",$service['servicetext']))));
```

Did I just put a security bug into the site?

Can anyone point me to the correct, safe solution?

Comment: PHP<5.4? Magic quotes on? Why did you have the slash in the first place there?

Comment: `htmlspecialchars_decode` with default flags leave single quotes alone, if `$output` is used only as html output I would use `str_replace` but with the entity, `\'` to `&#039`

Comment: @Dharman I'm not sure. It's a legacy site and the "page builder" is primitive and from 2012. It should really be rebuilt but the client has made their decision. When I type the text into the page builder, it comes out the other end like this. Thanks for your comment though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No additional vulnerabilities are added through this.** They would either be already present, or already secured.

---

**In HTML**, the single quote `'` has no special meaning, removing backslashes is fine.

**In JavaScript**, single quotes are used to delimitate strings.

- If the content is outputted directly in a `<script>` tag, directly in a string, there might be a way to output something like `';alert('xss')`. Please note, that this is extremely far fetched, and that it would mean that the xss vector of attack is *already present*, if a user can make the system output their input in such a tag.
- If the content is outputted in html unescaped, as this seem the case here, nevermind the single quote, something like `<script>alert('xss');</script>` would work directly.

**In SQL**, escaping single quotes with a backslash was used to "secure" SQL queries before the use of parameterized queries became widespread. In that direction, server to client in an HTML document, this transformation is irrelevant.

If the content that is outputted however, is later sent back to the server, and then used in concatenated SQL queries, *then* it could be a risk, that would be easily mitigated by using PDO or Mysqli along with parameterized statements.

---

Basically, nothing that is not already an attack vector is added through the removal of the backslashes. If there could be a problem with the data being sent back to the server for SQL evaluation, the vector is already present if the SQL queries are concatenated. Since the content being sent to the client is transormed back into html entities, XSS is already a possible vector if the data is being supplied by the user.

## In conclusion, if:

- The content is not suplied by the user, at anytime, and;
- SQL queries are parameterized,

there is no problem with removing backslashes from single quotes in the situation described here.

Comment: Thank you, I am the only admin of the site and the content is only being presented, not submitted back again. Based on your detailed answer I am happy that this is not a security issue. Thank you for taking the time to explain this!

Answer (score -2):

What I understand in this case is that the output is following the [addslashes](https://php.net/manual/es/function.addslashes.php) rule. I don't think that it will be conditioning the security, because it is only changing the string value. It is important then if you connect to the Data Base to use PREPARED SQL Queries. Hope I help you clarifying :)

Comment: Hello. Changing the string value can be totally risky if done in a sql query. There's also the risks of xss to consider.

Comment: I hear. Write then,

Comment: Give reasons, then. You don't take a constructive approach. :(